# Converting Pandas Series Strings to Float

Tags: python, pandas, series, string-conversion

I have a dataFrame, df, with one of the columns::

```
print(df['MJD_DUPLICATE'])

0         (0, 56238, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,...
1         (-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1...
2         (0, 56269, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,...
```

Simply put, how do I convert this to a float in order to plot it up?

```
b = df.astype(float)
```

doesn't work neither does:

```
for i in range(len(mjds)):
    mjds[i] = [float(x) for x in mjds[i]]
```

Thanks!!

N.B.::

```
print(df['MJD_DUPLICATE'][0:][0:0])

(0, 56279, 0, 56539, 0, 56957, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Series([], Name: MJD_DUPLICATE, dtype: object)
```

Comment: Why do you need to convert to floats to plot?

Comment: Because otherwise I get a "ValueError: scatter requires y column to be numeric" error

Comment: The values in the tuples are not *numbers*?

Comment: They are in general, but I think the leading and trailing '(' and ')' is screwing things up

Answer (score 1):

Did you try creating a new column with in the dataframe that is a float and then plotting against that?

```
df['MJD_DUPLICATE_float'] = df['MJD_DUPLICATE'].astype(float)
```

Comment: Yup, tried this. Got::   ValueError: could not convert string to float: '(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)'

Comment: I would try then: df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True). You can check they types that you converted to by using; df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).dtypes

Comment: where are you getting the orginal data from?? maybe its how the data is being read in from the beginning? Can you share some information on the original data set?

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that transforms the individual row values then use [`.apply()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply)

```
data = {'a':[(' 1 ',' 2 ',' 3 '), ('2','3','4'), (3,4,5)],
        'b':[('1','2','3'), ('2','3','4'), ('3','4','5')]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def f(thing):
    return tuple(float(n) for n in thing)

converted = df['a'].apply(f)
df['a'] = converted



>>> converted
0    (1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
1    (2.0, 3.0, 4.0)
2    (3.0, 4.0, 5.0)
Name: a, dtype: object
>>> df
                 a          b
0  (1.0, 2.0, 3.0)  (1, 2, 3)
1  (2.0, 3.0, 4.0)  (2, 3, 4)
2  (3.0, 4.0, 5.0)  (3, 4, 5)
>>>
```

---

If your data looks like this

```
data = {'a':['''(1,2,3)''', '''(2,3,4)''', '''(3,4,5)'''],
        'b':['''(1,2,3)''', '''(2,3,4)''', '''(3,4,5)''']}
```

Change your function to deal with it

```
def f(thing):
        thing = thing.strip()
        thing = thing.replace('(', '')
        thing = thing.replace(')', '')
        thing = thing.split(',')
        return tuple(float(n) for n in thing)
```

Comment: I get a::     "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '('  error

Comment: I changed each item in the tuples to strings, even adding whitespace, and it still works.  If your data has other *issues* you need to determine what they are and deal with them in the function that you are applying.

Comment: Okay, so the above code runs and works, but I still can't plot anything...